# MySQL: ignore WHERE clause if column does not exist

Tags: mysql

I have a query which I need to run on different tables. In some of these tables the column `country` exists, in others not.
The query is: `SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = '$name' AND country = '$country'`

Is there a way to write the query so that the `AND country = '$country'` part is ignored if the `country` column does not exist?

Comment: Are you constructing this query programatically? If you are, then you'll have to know and handle the tables structure. If you're writing this query, then no; you simply need to omit `AND country = '$country'`.

Comment: This is not a mysql specific question, you have an application code problem, not a database one.

Comment: It might not be MySQL-specific, but it certainly is SQL-specific.

Comment: So there is no way of adding an IF or a CASE to ignore a specific clause if the column does not exist

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't think you should delete the question.  The answer is basically, you *could* do it in straight SQL, but for God's sake, **don't**.

Comment: You've got an answer below that shows that you _could_ do it in SQL specifically (which is to query the table structure in your query to determine if the table has that column), but due to the nature of writing queries in SQL, you shouldn't have to... Just check the schema and adjust the query to match. Keep the question here 

Comment: Your question about `IF` and `CASE`...  You are describing some form of "meta-SQL".  In SQL, the query needs to be well-defined.  tf you are talking something MySQL-specific, they call it "MySQL Stored Procedure Language".  In Oracle, it's PL/SQL.  In PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL.

Comment: I tried a couple pseudo-queries locally, and even with an in-line check for the column's existence and only including a `WHERE column = 'whatever'` conditionally based on that, it still failed due to the column not existing. So at runtime directly in MySQL, the answer seems to remain as "No". If you are using a separate programming language (which you still haven't clarified), you'd simply do `if (/* logic to determine if column in table */) { /* logic to query column */ }` (or similar, i.e. the library I commonly use has a `when()` method for these cases). Interesting question though!

Comment: Simple example: `SELECT (CASE WHEN true THEN col_a ELSE col_b END) AS \`column\` FROM my_table;` - Both `col_a` and `col_b` exist, and toggling the `WHEN` clause, both queries return different values as `column`. As soon as I change one of the `THEN` or `ELSE` values to `col_c`, which _doesn't_ exist, the query fails, regardless of what `WHEN` is set to. It has to evaluate the entire query, regardless of conditional execution, and no matter what, `col_c` does not exist, so the query straight-up doesn't run.

Comment: Now maybe I missed it , but could they not write a Concat Stored Procedure with logic in it to query the Information Schemea first, see if the column exists, if it does use that version of the querry and if not, use the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in straight SQL.  If you are sending the SQL query from another programming language, you can selectively add the condition to the query based on the table definition.  You can either hard-code the table definition in the program, or get it by querying the database for the table definition.

Hell, if that's the only thing changing the query, you could just have a list of table names with a boolean flag indicating if the `country` column is present.

(There is a solution to this problem in straight SQL, but it's **extremely** janky and therefore not recommended.  It involves querying `information_schema.tables`, generating the SQL statements in a file, and then running the file.  Very, very not recommended.)

Comment: You're probably correct that this query is being sent from another programming language, but be careful providing answers where you make that assumption; I thought the same thing, but added a comment instead. If it turns out there isn't an external factor, this answer would be wrong and I don't want you to get unnecessary downvotes. (Although you could simply delete this at that point, but you know what I mean )

Comment: That's what the "Not in straight SQL" means.

Comment: Yes I know, but then your answer is just "No", which typically means the question can simply be closed or deleted at that point. I'm not saying your answer is wrong or anything, but consider commenting for clarification in the future instead of (or before) posting an answer.

Comment: I disagree.  A question where the answer is simply, "No", can still be valuable.  But I will add information about how actually to do it in SQL, and why you shouldn't.

Comment: Yeah, there are some canonical questions where the answer is a simple "No", but nowadays, those are pretty rare, and are generally simply deleted (at least the ones I've seen recently). Appreciate the conversation, and the edit definitely helps cover the other base (it would be janky and pretty redundant, but would work). Cheers 

Answer (score 2):

### No.

All columns you reference in the query, even in conditional expressions, must exist in the tables you query.

An alternative solution is to write code to omit some column references from the query based on what you can discover about the table.

In other words, first check the metadata of the table, then format the query you want to run with or without the `country` column.

Another solution would be to run the query including the reference to the `country` column, and if it returns an error, catch the error in your application, then try the query without the reference to the `country` column.